# LibUsb mount hotplugged device

Tags: c, linux, popen

I have some code working using libusb. The code detects a USB device attach/detach event. When attached my code will make a folder `/media/usb_device` then mount my USB to this folder. For each command I use `popen`. My issue is I have to use a `sleep` command between the `mkdir` and `mount` commands.

Is there a way to make this more clean? Avoid the seemingly random `sleep`?
Second, how can I capture the `popen` output? A different stack overflow question showed the method I am using. No luck.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

static bool run_command(char* cmd) {
    sleep(2);
    bool cmd_success = false;
    char result[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(&result, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    FILE *f = popen(cmd, "r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error running command %s\n", cmd);
    }
    else {
        while(fgets(result, sizeof(result), f) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", result);
        }
        cmd_success = true;
    }

    pclose(f);
    return cmd_success;
}

void config_file_handler_init(void) {
    bool mkdir = run_command("mkdir /media/usb_device");
    bool mount = run_command("mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb_device");

    if(mkdir && mount) {
        printf("We found a USB and mounted it. Now we can look through the files and act!\n");
    }
}
```